# Can a Java programmer tell me what this snippet is doing?

Tags: java, encryption

This is supposed to decrypt a file. I'm trying to figure out the algorithm but am having a bit of an issue understanding what is going on. Any hints? Thanks!

```
      localStringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder("");
      localStringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder("");
      Matcher localMatcher = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-z_\\-]+\\.html").matcher(paramString); //paramString is the encrypted file
      localMatcher.find();
      String str2 = localMatcher.group();
for (Integer localInteger1 = Integer.valueOf(0); localInteger1
            .intValue() < str2.length(); localInteger1 = Integer
            .valueOf(1 + localInteger1.intValue())) {
        localStringBuilder2.append(1 + Math.round(str2
                .codePointAt(localInteger1.intValue()) % 3));
        if (localInteger1.intValue() < "fdjkhireuhsdthuirdfg".length())
            localStringBuilder2.append(1 + Math
                    .round("fdjkhireuhsdthuirdfg".codePointAt(localInteger1
                            .intValue()) % 3));
    }
```

**Update: Simplified Loop**

```
for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
        localStringBuilder2.append(1 + Math.round(str2
                .codePointAt(i) % 3));
        if (i < "fdjkhireuhsdthuirdfg".length())
            localStringBuilder2.append(1 + Math
                    .round("fdjkhireuhsdthuirdfg".codePointAt(i) % 3));
    }
```

And you can find complete source code over [here](https://compilr.com/lochie/decrypt/DataLoader.java)

***EDIT***
Big thanks to Vandey who solved the string produced: "21321223331121"

This however doesn't get the full answer.
The next part is (beats the hell out of me):

```
label249: if (localInteger2.intValue() < i);
    try
    {
      localStringBuilder1.append((char)(Integer.parseInt(str1.substring(0 + localInteger2.intValue(), 2 + localInteger2.intValue()), 16) - Integer.parseInt(localStringBuilder2.substring(localInteger2.intValue() / 2 % localStringBuilder2.length(), 1 + localInteger2.intValue() / 2 % localStringBuilder2.length()))));
      label327: localInteger2 = Integer.valueOf(2 + localInteger2.intValue());
      break label249;
      str3 = localStringBuilder1.toString();
    }
    catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException localStringIndexOutOfBoundsException)
    {
      break label327;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, forgot to format!

Comment: That is one hell of complicated way to write simple loop.

Comment: A lot of boxing and unboxing is what's going on! We're missing str2, also.

Comment: Looks like it's a decompiled code. the loop does some scrambling of the string or descrambling

Comment: I added a few of the variables I skimmed over before.

Comment: What are you having trouble understanding? Have you looked at the Javadoc for Matcher, String StringBuilder etc.?

Comment: @Serge, that's what I'm thinking. I'd like to rewrite this in a language I'm more proficient in - can anyone actually interpret what this is saying? :/

Comment: @tgdavies What does Matcher have to do with anything?

Comment: @tgdavies, well I don't understand codePointAt and a few other things. If someone could explain the process in english, I can rewrite it! :P

Comment: Matcher is one of the classes used in the code above, Roddy

Comment: @tgdavies - Ah, hadn't clicked 'show edit'. The original didn't have the Matcher lines.

Comment: @iLoch it seems that either your decompiler produces incorrect source text, or this stuff is in its place specially for you to make you spending days to understand what it is doing while the result of the computations will be just thrown away in 20 lines later

Comment: You can get rid of Math.round as well.

Comment: @AmitD, wow forgot I did that. Where'd you find it??? :D
And Serge, yeah maybe, but something tells me there may be valuable information in these html files.

Comment: codePointAt - is it in English? ;)

Comment: String toCompare = "fdjkhireuhsdthuirdf(g";for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
            char ch = str2.charAt(i);
            int charInt1 = ch % 3;

            sb.append(1 + Math.round(charInt1));

            if (i < toCompare.length()) {
                char ch2 = toCompare.charAt(i);
                int charInt2 = ch2 % 3;
                sb.append(1 + Math.round(charInt2));
            }
        }

Comment: Format and use it , this should be it. Or at least , it should be pretty close :D

Comment: @vandey I'll give it a shot, certainly seems like a step in the right direction :)

Comment: I have also answered it, you can copy from there as well.

Comment: had a look at your source code. where is the return statement of loadEncrypted() ?

Comment: Mmm, that's not a working copy of the code. I'll update it. It's in a big while statement, so the return value is actually at the top: return str3; Check for updated code in a few seconds. Here: https://compilr.com/lochie/comactivisionelite/Project.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

str2 is hardcoded here, work for it , otherwise it shoould be pretty close to it. Anyone, feel free to edit it to the right direction.  The last printline was added just to see what it prints .
And sorry for misleading variable name.

```
    String str2 = "abcdefg";
    String toCompare = "fdjkhireuhsdthuirdf(g"; //looks like this changed when  you updated your question
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str2.charAt(i);
        int charInt1 = ch % 3;

        sb.append(1 + Math.round(charInt1));

        if (i < toCompare.length()) {
            char ch2 = toCompare.charAt(i);
            int charInt2 = ch2 % 3;
            sb.append(1 + Math.round(charInt2));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString()); // printed 21321223331121
```

Comment: Yes! This is it. "21321223331121". Ok, now what I've realized is that I haven't really given you guys enough of the information. Editing the OP. Will upvote this once I get enough rep. :/

Comment: Thanks again for this. Removing the bracket yielded the result. For anyone who was interested: This string is generated using the filename. ie, the str2 in the example above would be "index.html". From there, the characters are matched in order over and over until the html file has been read all the way though - bam, decoded.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set a breakpoint and go through the code step by step as it is executed. Watch the different expressions and use this information what the code does. This should be much easier than just to look at the code and try to understand.

Comment: Not a bad idea - just not sure I want to install Eclipse or another IDE just to do this..

Comment: @Roddy javac isn't a debugger.  There is jdb but that's not a nice thing to wish on somebody. iLoch, installing an IDE isn't anything to fret over.  I recommend IDEA over Eclipse though.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see, for every character of the str2, the stringBuilder is going to append a two digit number for each loop, the number been comprised of digits 1,2&3, which means a total of 9 such numbers is possible. You will ultimately get a series of 1,2,3...(not in order) and each pair of consecutive characters, will suggest a group of characters, but the token for each decrypted character will vary with the position of the pair of digits in the stringbuilder.

Also, for each consecutive pairs of digits in stringBuilder, only three  2digit numbers are possible, since the 2nd place of the digit is fixed by your "fdjk..." string.

Answer (score 0):

iLoch,

take a look at your class and at function. This function accesses only local variables, it returns nothing (while it should return a string).

What you are going to get from it?

Comment: My understanding is that it's going to turn an "encrypted" (ie. basically just scrambled) HTML file into an actual HTML file. I'll put up the file and you guys can have at it while I try for myself.

Comment: As Victor stated below, it may actually be a map; it could tell the program to shift the characters by a given value. view-source:http://pastesite.com/45049

Comment: what map??? the class has no parent class, the function has no inputs nor outputs. you are throwing away your time